# When and how to use std::locale::messages?

Tags: c++, c++11, internationalization, locale, facet

The C++ standard defines six categories of facets: `collate`, `ctype`, `monetary`, `numeric`, `time`, and `messages`.

I have known the usage of the first five, but I don't know when and how to use the last one: `std::locale::messages`.

Any illustrative examples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::locale::messages`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/messages) is used for opening message catalogues (most commonly GNU [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/))  including translated strings. Here is an [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/messages/open) which opens an existing message catalogue using on Linux (for `sed`) in German, retrieves (using `get()`) and outputs the translations for the English strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::locale loc("de_DE.utf8");
    std::cout.imbue(loc);
    auto& facet = std::use_facet<std::messages<char>>(loc);
    auto cat = facet.open("sed", loc);
    if(cat < 0 )
        std::cout << "Could not open german \"sed\" message catalog\n";
    else
        std::cout << "\"No match\" in German: "
                  << facet.get(cat, 0, 0, "No match") << '\n'
                  << "\"Memory exhausted\" in German: "
                  << facet.get(cat, 0, 0, "Memory exhausted") << '\n';
    facet.close(cat);
}
```

which outputs:

```
"No match" in German: Keine Übereinstimmung
"Memory exhausted" in German: Speicher erschöpft
```

**Edit**: Clarification according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931669/when-and-how-to-use-stdlocalemessages#comment28163494_18940351).

Comment: Not just GNU gettext. Message catalogs are part of POSIX (e.g., gencat(1), catopen(3)). Windows also has message catalogs, though I'm not sure if they've ever bothered to implement the standard locale message facets.